# Retrieve data from an other database (Android & Nativescript vue js)

Tags: android, vue.js, local-storage, nativescript, android-contentprovider

I have two apps. the first one built in android studio and the second one built with nativescript vue js. I want to send (or retrieve) some data from the first database to the second. 
can you help me with sample codes please ?

Comment: What kind of data you are trying pass? Is it sensitive information that other apps should not be able to access? What database you are using?

Comment: I used sqlite. In the first database I stored location data (longitude and latitude). No sensitive information. If it's possible to have a common database for both applications telle what can i manage. apps are designed via android studio and nativescrip vue

Comment: You have to use [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider) / [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) to share your data / db file between apps. Remember with NativeScript you are still building a native app and have access to all device features only that your syntax can be JavaScript.